# Trying to crawl all newslinks in a site (the parsed link only shows 10 results per page, I would need to find ALL links)

Tags: python, parsing, while-loop, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl all news link that has a certain keyword that is looking for.

```
 import urllib.request
 import urllib.parse
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import re

 key_word = urllib.parse.quote("금리")
 url = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=news&query=" + key_word +"%EA%B8%88%EB%A6%AC&sm=tab_opt&sort=0&photo=0&field=0&reporter_article=&pd=3&ds=2020.04.13&de=2020.04.14&docid=&nso=so%3Ar%2Cp%3Afrom20200413to20200414%2Ca%3Aall&mynews=0&refresh_start=0&related=0"
 html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

 anchor_set = soup.findAll('a')
 news_link = []

 for a in anchor_set:
 if str(a).find('https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?') != -1:
        a = a.get('href')
        news_link.append(a)'
```

Untill this section (code above), I parse into the url and retrieve all links that has a certian read.nhn(naver news platform) and append it to news_link.

This is working fine, but the proble is the url used above only shows 10 articles in the page.

```
count_tag = soup.find("div",{"class","title_desc all_my"})
count_text=count_tag.find("span").get_text().split()
total_num=count_text[-1][0:-1].replace(",","")
print(total_num)'
```

Using the code above I've found out there are a total of 1297 articles that I need to collect. but since the original link above only has 10 articles in the page.

```
for val in range(int(total_num)//10+1):
    start_val=str(val*10+1)
```

I was told i needed to insert this into the url to retrieve ALL newslinks.

Thus, I've used the while method

```
while start_val <= total_num:
     url = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=news&query=" + key_word +"%EA%B8%88%EB%A6%AC&sm=tab_opt&sort=0&photo=0&field=0&reporter_article=&pd=3&ds=2020.04.13&de=2020.04.14&docid=&nso=so%3Ar%2Cp%3Afrom20200413to20200414%2Ca%3Aall&mynews=0&refresh_start=" + start_val + "&related=0"

     html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

     news_link = []
     anchor_set = soup.findAll('a')

     for a in anchor_set:
         if str(a).find('https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?') != -1:
                 a = a.get('href')
                 news_link.append(a)
```

However, when I run the program, it seems the loop does not stop. obviously there is no else or break.. How can i break this loop and successfully collect all the links?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your current `while` loop doesn't stop because you haven't incremented the value of `start_val`. Also, later you have `range(int(total_num)//10+1)` so if you converted `total_num` to a string, then the string comparison in `while start_val <= total_num` is wrong - for *strings* `"21" > "1297"`, because `"2" > "1"`. Compare them as int's.

   And since you're creating the sequence of `val`s to use, you don't need a separate upper bound check.

   So far, this would give you the correct finite loop:

   ```
   for val in range(int(total_num)//10+1):  # no upper bound check needed
       start_val=str(val*10+1)
       url = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=news&query=" ...
       html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
       ...
   ```
2. For the values needed for the pages/next starting item, instead of doing:

   ```
   for val in range(int(total_num)//10+1):
       start_val = str(val*10+1)
   ```

   You can get the actual `val`'s from [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). To starting at 1 and going in steps of 10 to get: 1, 11, 21, ... , upto and including the total:

   ```
   for val in range(1, total_num + 1, 10):
       start_val = str(val)  # don't need this assignment actually
   ```
3. Next thing: the URL for page 2 onwards is wrong. Currently, your while loop will generate the following URL for page 2:

   `https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=news&query=%EA%B8%88%EB%A6%AC%EA%B8%88%EB%A6%AC&sm=tab_opt&sort=0&photo=0&field=0&reporter_article=&pd=3&ds=2020.04.13&de=2020.04.14&docid=&nso=so%3Ar%2Cp%3Afrom20200413to20200414%2Ca%3Aall&mynews=0&refresh_start=11&related=0`

   But if you click on page "2" of the results, you get the URL:

   `https://search.naver.com/search.naver?&where=news&query=%EA%B8%88%EB%A6%AC%EA%B8%88%EB%A6%AC&sm=tab_pge&sort=0&photo=0&field=0&reporter_article=&pd=3&ds=2020.04.13&de=2020.04.14&docid=&nso=so:r,p:from20200413to20200414,a:all&mynews=0&cluster_rank=35&start=11&refresh_start=0`

   - The main difference is at the end: `&refresh_start=11` in yours vs `&start=11&refresh_start=0` actual. Since that format also works for page 1 (just checked), use that instead.
   - You have some extra characters in the section after the keyword: `...&query=" + key_word +"%EA%B8%88%EB%A6%AC&sm=tab_opt`. That `%EA%B8%88%EB%A6%AC` is from your previous search keyword.
   - You can also skip several unneeded URL parameters, by testing which are actually not needed.

Putting all that together:

```
for val in range(1, total_num + 1, 10):
    start_val = str(val)
    url = ("https://search.naver.com/search.naver?&where=news&query=" +
           key_word +
           "&sm=tab_pge&sort=0&photo=0&field=0&reporter_article=&pd=3&ds=2020.04.13&de=2020.04.14" +
           "&docid=&nso=so:r,p:from20200413to20200414,a:all&mynews=0&cluster_rank=51" +
           "&refresh_start=0&start=" +
           start_val)

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    ...  # etc.
```